# Value not updated by function

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to print the number of times a button was clicked but it always show the button is clicked 0 times. 
Tried googling but did not find any solution.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
count = 0

root = Tk()
def clicked(count):

    print("the button is clicked "+ str(count) +" times")
    count+= 1

b = Button(root, text = "click here", command =lambda : clicked(count))
b.pack(fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare `count` as global.

```
from tkinter import *
count = 0

root = Tk()
def clicked():
    global count  # Here you will modify the variable count
    print("the button is clicked "+ str(count) +" times")
    count+= 1

b = Button(root, text = "click here", command =lambda : clicked())
b.pack(fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yeah it worked thanks. had to change the variable name count also. i think it is a keyword in python.

Comment: You had issues with `count` because of conflicts between the global `count` and the function parameter (which was also named count), edited the answer, it works now, afaik count is not a keyword see [python_ref_keywords](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_keywords.asp)